# Pyinstaller : Failed to create process when packaging a file

Tags: python, process, packaging, pyinstaller

I am using Pyinstaller to package an app that I made. And when I type :

```
C:\Users\Hung Truong\Desktop\Python>pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed file.py
```

It gives the error:

```
failed to create process.
```

How can I fix this ? Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Why the .exe after pyinstaller? Isn't it a .py file?

Comment: That's what I'm told to do on a website

Comment: Either install pyinstaller via pip or download the latest release from their site, dont forget to install pywin32 as well (Windows specific). Then use the command "pyinstaller --onefile --windowed file.py" (no brackets).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue so I checked the file

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py
```

and there was an old python path which when I installed python installer

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

But later I renamed python.exe --> python2.exe, so I just changed the path

```
C:\Python27\python.exe --> C:\Python27\python2.exe
```

in file

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py
```

and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In `pyinstaller-script.py`

```
!c:\program files\python\python35-32\python.exe
```

alter this line with below code:

```
!"c:\program files\python\python35-32\python.exe"
```